# How to increase the daily quotas of route services requests to avoid the error "service invoked too many times a day: route"

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, quota

I have a google spreadsheet with the following script:

```js
function drivingdistance(start, end) {
  var key = "MY_KEY";
   var clientID = "MY_CLIENTID";
   Maps.setAuthentication(clientID, key);
var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder() .setOrigin(start) .setDestination(end) .getDirections();
var route = directions.routes[0];
var distance = route.legs[0].distance.value;
Logger.log(distance);
  return distance;
}
```

This function make a lot of request every day, because is triggered about 20 times a day, and make about 100 calls each time. So the total request a day exceeds the quotas limit of direction service in AppScript (the limit should be 1000 request).
I have also recently activated a billing account in google cloud platform, and I set the request limit of the directions API to "NO LIMIT", but this did not solve the problem for me. Every day I see the error: "service invoked too many times a day: route".

How can I do to increase or remove the daily request limit avoiding the error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the function as a custom function, the "cheapest" solution is to change a bit your approach: use a custom menu or trigger to refresh the data only when you really need / avoid making a call for each cell using the custom function on every spreadsheet opening / refreshing.

Related: [service invoked too many times for one day geocode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43597604/1595451)

Anyway, if you prefer to get billed for the Google Maps API usage of your script, you have to create a Google Cloud Platform project and link your script to it.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects

Comment: The refresh is already triggered only when is needed (about 20 times a day), because I have adjusted the formula into the cells in order to inactive the custom function if not necessary.

Comment: Furthermore the script is already linked to my project in Google Cloud Platform. I found out that Maps.setAuthentication() doesn't work (I added my KEY and one of my "ID client OAuth 2.0"), maybe is this the problem? How can I use my KEY into my script in order to avoid the quotas error? Please note I have a billing account in GCP